# Get aria-label from html using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way to get the value of the aria-label using jQuery?

I have this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("dom ready")
    $(document).on('click', '.clicker', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var hrefValue = this.href;
        var label = this.aria - label;
        var id = this.id;
        console.log("aria label " + label);
        fire(hrefValue)
    });
});
```

Which works if I want to get the `hrefValue` from this dropdown:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle rootelements clicker" role="button" aria-label="'+elem.appname+'" data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" title=' + elem.link + ' href="' + elem.value +'"><i style="color:' + elem.iconcolor + ';" class="' + elem.icon + '" id="jsonicon"></i></a>
```

But this `console.log("aria label " +label)`
Returns `aria label NaN` for me when expected output is `debug`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
var label = $(this).attr('aria-label');
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. 
Why do I not need this to get the href value as well?

Comment: @Thomas Thats because when you're using `this` inside the callback `click` function it points to the DOM element which is similar but still different from jQuery elements. Anchor elements from the DOM API have a `href` property which you're using to read the value. If you were to do this with jQuery completely it would look something like:
`var hrefValue = $(this).attr('href');`

The important take is: If you wanna use jQuery inside callbacks such as these, make sure to wrap the DOM element object inside the jQuery shorthand function: `$(<DOM element here>)`

Answer (score 2):

You can either use camel case or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) since `aria-label` contains a hyphen, which makes it not a valid identifier, so it cannot be used in [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation).

```
var label = this.ariaLabel;
// or
var label = this['aria-label'];
```

Comment: Be aware that this is still a [Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#dom-ariamixin-arialabel). Unfortunaly this means not all [browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=ariaLabel) currently support this notation.